# Quotient of multiplicative real numbers by subgroup generated by $\pi$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider $G=(R^*,1,*)$, multiplicative group of real numbers and his cyclic subgroup generated by $N=\langle\,\pi\,\rangle$.
Consider then $G/N$. How many elements of order $n$ are there in $G/N$?

My try:
I think the answer is $n-1$. The classes $\bigl[\pi^{\frac mn}\bigr]$ with $0<m<n$.

Edit:
I think my previous answer is wrong, they are less than $n-1$, precisely i think there are $\phi(n)$ where $\phi$ is the Euler function(the one dealing with coprimes).

Comment: Do you mean the number of elements of order $n$ or whose order divides $n$

Comment: Your approach is correct because $\Bbb{R}_{> 0}^\times$ is abelian torsion free thus the $n$-th power is bijective so the $n$-th root is well-defined

Comment: I mean the number of elements of order n. I have edited my answer in, i think, more correct one.

Comment: What happens if $\gcd(m,n) \ne 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An element $x$ has order $n$ if $x^n = 1$ but $x^k \neq 1$ for any $k<n$.

If $x^n = [1]$ (in the quotient), by definition of $N$, then $x^n = \pi^m$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$.

So, $x=\pi^{\frac{m}{n}}$ or, if $n$ is even, it is also possible that $x = -\pi^{\frac{m}{n}}$.

You want the order to be precisely $n$, so as you correctly said the number of possible $m$ is given by $\varphi(n)$, the totient function, as you want $m$ and $n$ to be coprime (otherwise $x^{n'} = \pi^{m'}$ for $n'<n$, which contradicts $n$ being minimal), and you can assume that $m<n$ without loss of generality.

So the answer is $\varphi(n)$ when $n$ is odd, and $2\varphi(n)$ when $n$ is even.